# Element not interactable Error when clicking a child element that is in a parent element which was extracted using a child element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

There are two similar buttons (let's call them "Install" buttons) in the DOM, but I need to select the button using a text that is only available for the HTML block that the button is in.

This is the code I used, and below is the output I got:

```
    disable_operation_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Disable Operation Re-executing')]")
    parent_element_disable_button = disable_operation_button.find_element(By.XPATH, "../../../..")
    
    print(parent_element_disable_button.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
    print("**************isdisplayed")

    # Printing whether the Install button is displayed
    print(parent_element_disable_button.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ant-btn ant-btn-primary']//span[contains(text(), 'Install')]").is_displayed())

    parent_element_disable_button.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ant-btn ant-btn-primary']//span[contains(text(), 'Install')]").click()
```

And the output for `parent_element_disable_button` is below (please note that in the last 2 lines the **Install button** is there):

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
   <div style="text-align: right; display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse;">
      <div style="margin: 8px 0px 8px 8px;">
         <label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper">
            <span class="ant-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value=""><span class="ant-checkbox-inner"></span></span>
            <span>
               Disable Operation Re-executing 
               <span role="img" aria-label="question-circle" class="anticon anticon-question-circle">
                  <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="question-circle" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M512 64C264.6 64 64 264.6 64 512s200.6 448 448 448 448-200.6 448-448S759.4 64 512 64zm0 820c-205.4 0-372-166.6-372-372s166.6-372 372-372 372 166.6 372 372-166.6 372-372 372z"></path>
                     <path d="M623.6 316.7C593.6 290.4 554 276 512 276s-81.6 14.5-111.6 40.7C369.2 344 352 380.7 352 420v7.6c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h48c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V420c0-44.1 43.1-80 96-80s96 35.9 96 80c0 31.1-22 59.6-56.1 72.7-21.2 8.1-39.2 22.3-52.1 40.9-13.1 19-19.9 41.8-19.9 64.9V620c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h48c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-22.7a48.3 48.3 0 0130.9-44.8c59-22.7 97.1-74.7 97.1-132.5.1-39.3-17.1-76-48.3-103.3zM472 732a40 40 0 1080 0 40 40 0 10-80 0z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </span>
         </label>
      </div>
      <div style="margin: 8px 0px 8px 8px;"><label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper"><span class="ant-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value=""><span class="ant-checkbox-inner"></span></span><span>Schedule Install</span></label></div>
      <div style="margin: 8px;"><label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper"><span class="ant-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value=""><span class="ant-checkbox-inner"></span></span><span>Block Uninstall</span></label></div>
   </div>
   <span style="display: none;">
      <div class="ant-picker">
         <div class="ant-picker-input">
            <input readonly="" placeholder="Select Time" title="" size="18" autocomplete="off" value="">
            <span class="ant-picker-suffix">
               <span role="img" aria-label="calendar" class="anticon anticon-calendar">
                  <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="calendar" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M880 184H712v-64c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8h-56c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v64H384v-64c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8h-56c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v64H144c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v664c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h736c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V216c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32zm-40 656H184V460h656v380zM184 392V256h128v48c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h56c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-48h256v48c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h56c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-48h128v136H184z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </span>
   <button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" style="margin: 5px;"><span>Install</span></button>
</div>
```

For the output of displaying whether the Install button element is present in DOM it shows False.

```
**************isdisplayed
False
```

When clicking on the install button (`parent_element_disable_button.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ant-btn ant-btn-primary']//span[contains(text(), 'Install')]").click()`) it throws the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Can you please suggest a way to fix this or select the button?

Answer (score 0):

May suggest to change isDisplayed check -> ExpectedCondition. elementToBeClickable(By locator) + add some wait before you click on this button.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath")))
```

Also there is a chance and may help:

- move to element (using Actions) / scroll to element and only then click
- click button via JavaScriptExecutor (if no luck with the attempts above).

Anyway, I guess waiting should help for you besides any extra tricks.

Comment: I tried out expectedConditions, but in this case it timedout. 
The thing was in the above code it selected the 1st button despite i try to get the second button via parent and child elements.
Do you happens to know a way to get the second button element with a part of a text? like `parent_element_disable_button` in the above?

Comment: @ArshanaAtapattu you're trying to click on the '//button[@class='ant-btn ant-btn-primary']//span[contains(text(), 'Install')]", maybe you shuld try to click to the btn? I mean '//button[@class='ant-btn ant-btn-primary']//span[contains(text(), 'Install')]/ancestor::button'

Comment: hi maria, it's now solved by using `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ant-btn ant-btn-primary']//span[contains(text(), 'Install')]")[1].click()`